# How to create pre-push hook in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

Is there a way in mercurial to run a hook before doing a push. For example I'd like to run JSHint over the codebase when I type `hg push` and abort the push when any errors are found.

I first tried using a `pre-commit` hook. That worked, but it's a nuisance to wait a few seconds before each commit. Besides, I'd like to sometimes do intermediate commits with possibly broken code.

Reading the [docs for hgrc](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/hgrc) I discovered `preoutgoing` and `pre-outgoing` which seemed like the thing I'd like. But these didn't work. The only thing they seem to do is run the hook when I type:

```
hg outgoing
```

Not useful for me at all.

Answer (score 6):

Found a solution. Posting it here in case somebody else is wondering about the same thing.

Turns out the documentation was just confusing for me. It told:

> `"pre-<command>"`
>
> > Run before executing the associated command. The contents of the command line are passed as "$HG_ARGS". Parsed command line arguments are passed as "$HG_PATS" and "$HG_OPTS". These contain string representations of the data internally passed to . "$HG_OPTS" is a dictionary of options (with unspecified options set to their defaults). "$HG_PATS" is a list of arguments. If the hook returns failure, the command doesn't execute and Mercurial returns the failure code.

I thought that the `<command>` it referred to is one of the hook types like `outgoing` or `commit` and I couldn't find a `push` hook listed there. But turns out the command is just any mercurial command, so I can just use `pre-push`.

Issue solved :)